# AWS-CDK: Need to pass resource generated in pipeline to a created stack

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm currently working on a cross-account deployment pipeline.

I'm using 4 different stacks:

- BackendPipelineStack
- CommonInfrastructureStack
- AssetDeploymentStack
- BusinessAssetAPIStack

The last 2 stacks both have `props` that include a generated `Layer` and built JS files (for the different Lambdas).

My `cdk.ts` looks like this:

```
import * as cdk from "@aws-cdk/core"
import { BackendPipelineStack } from "../lib/backend-pipeline"
import { BusinessAssetAPIStack } from "../lib/business-asset-api-stack"
import { projectConfig } from "../config/config"
import { AssetDeploymentStack } from "../lib/asset-deployment-stack"
import { CommonInfrastructureStack } from "../lib/common-infrastructure-stack"
const app = new cdk.App()
const commonInfraStack = new CommonInfrastructureStack(app, "CommonInfrastructureStack", {
  stackName: `${projectConfig.resourcePrefix}-common-infrastructure-stack`,
})
const apiStack = new BusinessAssetAPIStack(app, "BusinessAssetAPIStack", {
  stackName: `${projectConfig.resourcePrefix}-business-asset-api-stack`,
  ...,
  installationUserEmailIndexName: commonInfraStack.installationTechnicalAssetUserEmailIndexName,
})
const deploymentStack = new AssetDeploymentStack(app, "AssetDeploymentStack", {
  stackName: `${projectConfig.resourcePrefix}-asset-deployment-stack`,
  ...,
  installationAccountRegionIndexName: commonInfraStack.installationAccountRegionIndexName,
})

new BackendPipelineStack(app, "BackendPipelineStack", {
  nonProdAccountId: "nonProdAccountId",
  apiStack,
  commonInfraStack,
  deploymentStack,
})
```

My `BackendPipelineStack` stack is the one generating the `codepipeline.Artifact`s that store both the built JS files and `Layer`s.

```
//backend-pipeline.ts
export class BackendPipelineStack extends Stack {
   ...
   const lambdaBuildOutput = new Artifact("DistArtifact")
   const lambdaLayer = new Artifact("LayerArtifact")
   ...
```

I want to be able to pass both `Artifacts` to the other stacks that are passed thru the PipelineStack constructor.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Does `BackendPipelineStack` create an AWS CodePipeline? If yes, is the pipeline created using CDK pipelines https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2//docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html ?

Comment: No, it's the `@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for those who would be stuck in the same situation as I was.

Looking into pipeline actions, there is one called `CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack` that allows to override parameters provided in the Lambda Stack thru `CfnParametersCode` [(here's a python example)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/CfnParametersCode.html).